# calling c code from c++

Tags: c++, c

how does a call from c++ to c work internally??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a heavy duty implementation detail.  But most C++ compilers I know don't try to do anything special to differentiate a C function from a non-instance C++ function.  Just the plain olden cdecl calling convention for both.

Kinda important because the CRT implementation, with functions like printf(), are just as usable by a C compiler as they are by the C++ compiler from the same vendor.  Nobody wants to maintain two versions of it.

Comment: For reference, how does `extern "C"` factor in?

Comment: @cHao it stops the name mangling that c++ does to support operator overloading, e.g. `foo(int)` and `foo(double)` might translate to `foo_int` and `foo_double` in the assembly emitted by the compiler, but `extern "C" foo(int)` and `extern "C" foo(double)` both translate simply to `foo`

Comment: It changes the name of the identifier as seen by the linker.  Turns off the C++ name mangling.  All traditional CRT functions are extern "C" in their declaration as seen by the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ compiler 'does the right thing' and uses the correct calling convention for the C function - a lame sounding answer but I don't know that there's much more that can be said!